# Parsing through dataframe to create a string in R

Tags: r, directed-acyclic-graphs

I have a dataframe like so in R

I want to be able to make a function to prompt the user to change the value of 'e' given inputs for 'v' and 'w' and output a string of the dependencies.

```
   v  w  e  
1  d  f -- 
2  d  a -> 
3  f  a -> 
4  q  a ->
```

The function would look like so:

```
convert_dag <- function(df,v,w,e) {

}
```

and the expected output would look like so: it would first list all unique values then the dependencies.

```
> str <- convert_dag(df, 'q','f','<--')
> str
dag {
a
d
f
q
d <- f
d -> a
f -> a
q -> a
}
```

that way i can use it as input to the 'dagitty()' function to create a DAG graph.

```
g <- dagitty(str)
```

My solution:

```
convert_dag <- function(df,v,w,e) {
  z <- 'dag{'
  for (row in 1:nrow(df)) {
    if (df[row,'v'] == v && df[row,'w'] == w) {
      z <- paste(z,paste(df[row,'v'], e, df[row,'w']), collapse = '')
    } else {
      z <- paste(z,paste(df[row,'v'], df[row,'e'], df[row,'w']), collapse = '')
    }
  }
  z <- paste(z,'}')
  z
}
```

I don't like this soluion however, is there a more efficient cleaner way of writing this code?

Comment: You won't want to call your function `t()`. Most likely, see `?t`.

Comment: Edited it to `convert_dag()`

Comment: Updated with my solution.

Answer (score 0):

Is that the point?

```
library(tidyverse)
df = tribble(
  ~v,  ~w,  ~e,  
  "d", "f",  "--", 
  "d", "a",  "->", 
  "f", "a",  "->", 
  "q", "a",  "->")

convert_dag = function(df,V,W,E) {
  df %>% mutate(
    txt = ifelse(v==V & w==W, paste(V,E,W), paste(v,e,w))
  ) %>% pull(txt) %>% paste(.,collapse = " ") %>%  paste('dag{',.,'}')
}
convert_dag(df, "d", "f", "->")
#[1] "dag{ d -> f d -> a f -> a q -> a }"
```

Did you duplicate your question?

[Loop through dataframe to get a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69136734/loop-through-dataframe-to-get-a-string/69137888#69137888)