# Loop through dataframe to get a string

Tags: r, tidyverse

I have like a dataframe like so:

```
  v w  e  
1 d f  -- 
2 d a  -> 
3 f a  -> 
4 q a  ->
```

and wrote this function:

```
convert_dag <- function(df,v,w,e) {
  z <- 'dag{'
  for (row in 1:nrow(df)) {
    if (df[row,'v'] == v && df[row,'w'] == w) {
      z <- paste(z,paste(df[row,'v'], e, df[row,'w']), collapse = '')
    } else {
      z <- paste(z,paste(df[row,'v'], df[row,'e'], df[row,'w']), collapse = '')
    }
  }
  z <- paste(z,'}')
  z
}
```

This function will take the dataframe and update values based on user input and output a string. My question is if there is a more efficient way of writing this code using tidyverse syntax?

Example:

```
> convert_dag(df,'d','f','->')
[1] "dag{ d -> f d -> a f -> a q -> a }"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Of course it does.

```
library(tidyverse)
df = tribble(
  ~v,  ~w,  ~e,  
  "d", "f",  "--", 
  "d", "a",  "->", 
  "f", "a",  "->", 
  "q", "a",  "->")

convert_dag = function(df,V,W,E) {
  df %>% mutate(
    txt = ifelse(v==V & w==W, paste(V,E,W), paste(v,e,w))
  ) %>% pull(txt) %>% paste(.,collapse = " ") %>%  paste('dag{',.,'}')
}
convert_dag(df, "d", "f", "->")
#[1] "dag{ d -> f d -> a f -> a q -> a }"
```

**Update 1**

```
n = 40
tibble(
  id = 1:n,
  V = sample(c("d", "f", "q"), n, replace = TRUE),
  W = sample(c("a", "f"), n, replace = TRUE),
  e = sample(c("--", "->", "<-", "->>", "<<-"), n, replace = TRUE)
) %>% group_by(id) %>% 
  nest(data=V:e) %>% 
  mutate(con_dag = map(data, ~convert_dag(df, .x$V, .x$W, .x$e))) %>% 
  unnest(data:con_dag)
```

output

```
# A tibble: 40 x 5
# Groups:   id [40]
      id V     W     e     con_dag                            
   <int> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr>                              
 1     1 q     f     ->>   dag{ d -- f d -> a f -> a q -> a } 
 2     2 f     a     ->    dag{ d -- f d -> a f -> a q -> a } 
 3     3 f     f     --    dag{ d -- f d -> a f -> a q -> a } 
 4     4 f     a     ->    dag{ d -- f d -> a f -> a q -> a } 
 5     5 q     a     ->>   dag{ d -- f d -> a f -> a q ->> a }
 6     6 q     a     <<-   dag{ d -- f d -> a f -> a q <<- a }
 7     7 q     f     <<-   dag{ d -- f d -> a f -> a q -> a } 
 8     8 f     f     <-    dag{ d -- f d -> a f -> a q -> a } 
 9     9 d     a     ->    dag{ d -- f d -> a f -> a q -> a } 
10    10 q     a     ->    dag{ d -- f d -> a f -> a q -> a } 
# ... with 30 more rows
```

Note, due to the specific construction of the `tibble` mutation, it must contain one grouping variable. Here it is the variable `id`.

**Update 2**

```
tibble(
  id = 1:2,
  V = c('d','d'),
  W = c('f','a'),
  e = c('->','<-')
) %>% group_by(id) %>%
  nest(data=V:e) %>%
  mutate(con_dag = map(data, ~convert_dag(df, .x$V, .x$W, .x$e))) %>%
  unnest(data:con_dag)
```

output

```
# A tibble: 2 x 5
# Groups:   id [2]
     id V     W     e     con_dag                           
  <int> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr>                             
1     1 d     f     ->    dag{ d -> f d -> a f -> a q -> a }
2     2 d     a     <-    dag{ d -- f d <- a f -> a q -> a }
```

Is it clearer now?

**Update 3**

```
convert_dag2 = function(df,V,W,E) {
  df %>% mutate(
    test = v %in% V & w %in% W,
    txt = ifelse(test, paste(V,E,W), paste(v,e,w))
  ) %>% pull(txt) %>% paste(.,collapse = " ") %>%  paste('dag{',.,'}')
}
convert_dag2(df, c('d','d'), c('f','a'), c('->','<-'))
# [1] "dag{ d -> f d <- a f -> a q -> a }"
```

Comment: This is really great. Do you know how to adapt this code if the inputs are now lists? For example.. the following would give me the following result.

`convert_dag(df, c('d','d'), c('f','a'), c('->','<-'))
#[1]"dag{ d -> f d <- a f -> a q -> a }"`

Comment: Hmm, on the `lists`? Why not on `tibble`? Nothing needs to be changed in the function `convert_dag`. You just need to manipulate the '`tibble` appropriately. See for my update.

Comment: I don't understand your solution. The output should still be a string. But the inputs V,W,E are now lists where the 0th element of each list would be a change, and the 1st element, and so on.

Comment: Take a look at my `tibble`. The variable `V = c ('d', 'd')`, the variable `W = c ('f', 'a')` and the variable `e = c ('->', '<-')`. Is this not what you expected? These values of the variables `V`, `W` and `e` must result in two equal strings that you find in the variable `con_dag`

Comment: Sorry I'm a bit confused. It seems like `con_dag` is a string for each change. However it should be one change entirely. I.e.  the string "dag{ d -> f d <- a f -> a q -> a }" should be outputted

Comment: You write in such a confusing manner. Moreover, you are asking for one weave in several threads! If you write more clearly, you won't have to run multiple threads simultaneously. I also hope that on this second thread you will mark my answer as accepted and that you will give the answer is useful.