# Converting dataframe to string given an input of lists in R

Tags: r

I asked a question prior on converting  a dataframe to a string like so.

```
library(tidyverse)
df = tribble(
  ~v,  ~w,  ~e,  
  "d", "f",  "--", 
  "d", "a",  "->", 
  "f", "a",  "->", 
  "q", "a",  "->")

test = function(df,V,W,E) {
  df %>% mutate(
    txt = ifelse(v==V & w==W, paste(V,E,W), paste(v,e,w))
  ) %>% pull(txt) %>% paste(.,collapse = " ") %>%  paste('dag{',.,'}')
}
test(df, "d", "f", "->")
#[1] "dag{ d -> f d -> a f -> a q -> a }"
```

I want to be able to give a list of arguments for V, W,and E now. How can I adapt my code to do so?

Expected Output:

For example.. I would update the `convert_dag()` function to take in lists now and get the following output:

```
convert_dag(df, c('d','d'), c('f','a'), c('->','<-'))
#[1]"dag{ d -> f d <- a f -> a q -> a }"
```

Comment: This applies to the question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69136734/loop-through-dataframe-to-get-a-string/69137888#69137888

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
library(tidyverse)

df = tribble(
  ~v,  ~w,  ~e,
  "d", "f",  "--",
  "d", "a",  "->",
  "f", "a",  "->",
  "q", "a",  "->")


convert_dag2 = function(df,V,W,E) {
  df %>% mutate(
    test = v %in% V & w %in% W,
    txt = ifelse(test, paste(V,E,W), paste(v,e,w))
  ) %>% pull(txt) %>% paste(.,collapse = " ") %>%  paste('dag{',.,'}')
}
convert_dag2(df, c('d','d'), c('f','a'), c('->','<-'))
#[1] "dag{ d -> f d <- a f -> a q -> a }"
```